# Is there a way to remove unowned SKPhysicsNode in SKScene SpriteKit Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm developing a game in swift using SpriteKit. I create an empty Scene using `SKScene()`, then present it on `SKView` and enable `showsNodeCount` and `showsPhysics`. Then in the center of my scene appears a circle of physics object, which is `<SKPhysicsBody> type:<Circle> representedObject:[(null)]` with `collisionBitMask` set to `4294967295`.

[Screenshot of en empty scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmQzm.jpg)

The debug node count states 1 node, but physics body `node` property is `nil` and scene's `children` array is empty. My guess is that it is a scene node.

IDK if related, but graphs and entities are empty too.

I set `collisionBitMask` to 0 at `sceneDidLoad()` using `physicsWorld.body(at: .zero)`, but it get's a bit on my nerves, and looks a bit like a crutch. Is there a way to get rid of it, instead of changing `collisionBitMask`?

Comment: please clarify the question. you're adding something to the scene, but you want the node count to read zero? or your scene is empty and you're wondering why it says 1 node? in my experience an entirely empty SKScene will still say node:1 -- my guess is this is a count of the SKScene itself (which inherits from SKEffectNode, which inherits from SKNode)

Comment: My scene is completely empty and unconfigured, but there is a SKPhysicsBody circle with no parent node, with collisionBitMask set to all ones. Is there a way to remove it from the scene?

Comment: an empty SKScene will not come prepopulated with a SKPhysicsBody. did you add one? are you perhaps loading from an .sks file?

Comment: I didn't add any SKPhysicsBody and was creating a scene using ```SKScene()``` with no .sks files in project